# Finding variables of QgsPolygon and QgsPolyline?

Tags: pyqgis, polygon

now I want to use QgsPolygon (and Qgspolyline,too) class in python

I have a example by using QgsPoint but I don't know how to use in QgsPolygon

following is my Qgspoint example

```
    feature = QgsFeature()
    qpoint = QgsPoint( float(x), float(y) ) #get qpoint's attitube here
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(qpoint))#set point's geometry here
    if numpy.isnan(val):
        pass #no assign value means assign NULL value
    else:
        attr_val = round(val,4)
        feature.addAttribute(0,QVariant(attr_val))
    feature_list.append(feature)#append value here
```

I want to change QgsPolygon(or QgsPolyline) instead of QgsPoint 
but I couldn't find the variables of QgsPolygon(or QgsPolyline)

where to find the variables of QgsPolygon and QgsPolyline?

---

I have another problem here ,

```
  for s in dataset:
        x=s[0]
        y=s[1]      
        feature = QgsFeature()
        qpoint = QgsPoint( float(x) , float(y) )
        polygon=[]
        polygon.append(qpoint)

        feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([polygon]))
```

but it's still get

```
        TypeError: QgsFeature.setGeometry(): argument 1 has unexpeced type 'NoneType'
```

how to fix it?

Have I mistake the meaning of your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [Geometry Handling](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/geometry.html)

1. a point:   QgsPoint(x,y)
2. a line:    QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(x1,y1),QgsPoint(x2,y2)]))
3. a polygon: QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([[**QgsPoint(x1,y1)**,QgsPoint(x2,y2), QgsPoint(x3,y3),**QgsPoint(x1,y1)**]]) -> the polygon must be closed.

thus:

```
line_start= QgsPoint(50,50)
line_end= QgsPoint(100,100)
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start, line_end])
points = [QgsPoint(60,60),QgsPoint(60,80),QgsPoint(80,80),QgsPoint(80,60),QgsPoint(60,60)] 
polygon= QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points])
```

and:

```
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start, line_end]))
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points]))
```

Comment: the example Geometry Handling gives that not closed in polygon?
 gPolygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon( [ [ QgsPoint(1,1), QgsPoint(2,2), QgsPoint(2,1) ] ] )

Comment: It depends of the geometry

Comment: I have another problem above thanks for your help!

Comment: a Polygon is not a list but It is built from a list of points

Answer (score 0):

Look at the API documentation for QgsGeometry:

- 1.8 API http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsGeometry.html
- master API http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html

Comment: This is where they are defined http://qgis.org/api/1.8/qgsgeometry_8h.html#ae40bfa8c4815c0ea40009f8a13deae52