# How to create a polygon feature using Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm making a plugin for Quantum GIS in python. I have a polygon layer and want to create a new feature.

So far, I have this because I need a polygon geometry to add the feature:

```
surface = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon (polygon)
```

The problem is that I do not create a polygon. I have a list of points where I want to place the polygon.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you would probably get a quicker answer by googling for QgsGeometry.fromPolygon

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the same problem. The Cookbook (linked by [Dan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66879/12768)) is my main source, but this time it shows only how to make points, not polygons. I've solved it with [gene's answer elsewhere](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/64250/12768):

```
surface = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon ([points])
```

Assumming you have your points stored in a list named `points`. Don't forget the square brackets around the list's name.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a feature, but you're missing the step where you add this feature to the layer. Read through this page and replicate the samples. You'll work it through in no time.

http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#add-features

Comment: The linked chapter in the cookbook concerns only point geometries. Polygons seem more complicated, simply substituting "polygon" for "point" and a list of vertices for a single vertex doesn't work. So your link is not directly applicable in OP's (and my) case.